# How do I assign different fill and border colors to geom_point plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, format, geom-point

I am trying to color-code points on a geom_point plot to mirror team colors of major league baseball teams (e.g. New York Mets would have a blue-filled point with an orange border). There are similar stack overflow questions whose solutions I have tried to mirror, but with no success.

With the below code, the output applies the first set of colors (from scale_fill_manual) but does not apply the intended border color from scale_color_manual.

What is the proper technique?

[Current output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhdJQ.png)

```
#install.packages("Lahman")
library(Lahman)
library(ggthemes)

team_wins <- filter(Teams, yearID > 1990 & yearID != 1994 & yearID !=2020,
                    franchID %in% c('NYM','WSN','ATL','PHI','FLA'))

graph1 = team_wins %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=W, y=attendance)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, stroke = 0, shape = 21, size = 4, 
             aes(color = factor(franchID),
                 fill = factor(franchID))) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  labs(title = "Wins by NL East Teams over Time",
       subtitle = "From 1980 Onward",
       x = "# of Wins",
       y = "Attendance",
       #color = "WSWin",
       caption = "Source: Lahman Data") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(),
        text = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(55,110,5))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0,5000000,1000000))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("NYM" = "#002D72", 
                                "ATL" = "#CE1141",
                                "FLA" = "#00A3E0", 
                                "PHI" = "#E81828", 
                                "WSN" = "#14225A")) +

  scale_color_manual(values = c("NYM" = "#FF5910", 
                               "ATL" = "#13274F",
                               "FLA" = "#EF3340", 
                               "PHI" = "#FFFFFF", 
                               "WSN" = "#AB0003"))

graph1
```

I tried the code pasted above but the second set of colors are ignored.

Comment: Well, you have to draw your points with an outline, i.e. instead of `stroke = 0` use a stroke > 0

Comment: Appreciate the correction and response!

Comment: stefan's comment resolved your question completely, is that correct Violin125?

Comment: Correct, stefan's comment resolved my question. I had borrowed the "stroke = 0" statement from another use case and wasn't aware it controlled border thickness. Happy to upvote his solution if provided as an answer. (Very new here so please let me know if if I'm overlooking any follow-up on my end).